# Inverted Link chart- Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am new to highcharts. Is there anyway I can achieve kind of chart functionality using highcharts in which series label are on top and y axis is drawn vertically as shown in this image
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UHmi.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO Please embed images by prefixing the link with an exclamation mark ❗What do you mean by "this kind", please describe what you want to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

You just can build a chart with multiple y-axes and enabled `inverted` option:

```
    chart: {
        inverted: true
    },
    yAxis: [{
        opposite: true,
        width: '40%'
    }, {
        offset: 0,
        opposite: true,
        width: '50%',
        left: '50%'
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4eow5np2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.inverted

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek you are are life saver :) . just one more question regarding the inverted x axis in this fiddle you shared. I want to to set tickInterval on inverted x-axis based on y axis values.. is there anyway this can be achieved?

Comment: Hello @Waqas, For sure this is achievable, but you need to describe more precisely the case. What the relation between tick interval and y-axis values should look like?

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek, I have modified the fiddle slightly [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mbr1w43g/). If you see the 3rd point in the series its 57 177, but the tick on the xAxis is showing 2. How can this be changed to show the right intervals on the xAxis?.

Comment: What do you mean by `the right intervals`? What should be the value on x-axis?